# ASP.Net Web Api how to change token expiration time in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, authorization, bearer-token

For our `ASP.Net` application, we have recently implemented `Web API` usage. We use bearer token authentication. Our customer has ordered the opportunity to change token expiration time on the settings page and store it in the database. There is no problem to get it from database and change time in `Startup.Auth.cs`

```
static Startup()
{
    SettingsService _settingService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<SettingsService>();
    var hostSettings = _settingService.GetHostSettings();
    OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(hostSettings.ApiTokenExpirationTimeInHours),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider()
    };
}
```

But we have to restart the application each time we want to modify expiration time. How to modify `AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan` dynamically without app restart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of this problem was quite easy. `OAuthServerOptions` property was made as static public property with private setter

```
public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions { get; private set; }
```

So OAuth options are available outside of `Startup` class. And so when host settings are changed, expiration time can be freely changed

```
Startup.OAuthServerOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(hostSettings.ApiTokenExpirationTimeInHours);
```